# How to share data between django server and continuously running python script?

Tags: python, django, web, server

Basically I have a django app and a process which fetches some data from net and perform some computation and save output in a variable. Now whenever a request is made to server i want those data to be retreived and returned in response. How do I go about it? Saving in database ia an option but since this task will be running every second, I don't want to update database every time.

Comment: You could use a separate optimized database, global variables or a file to store the data

Comment: How will global variable works between 2 different processes?

Comment: Ok that wont work if it's two different processes. You should explain more what your process are doing.